# Unable to import selenium webdriver from within a function

Tags: python, function, selenium-webdriver, import

I have a few scripts, wherein I am required to import a few modules everytime. To avoid using the import statements everytime I write a new script, I tried to write a function as follows so that I can import the function instead. Here's how wrote the code for that :

```
def mylibs():

    import selenium
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.support import      expected_conditions as EC
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
    return
```

mylibs()

But when I am running the next line of the code- which should use the webdriver imported above to launch an instance of the chrome browser :

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(r"c:\users\nila9\drivers\chromedriver.exe")
```

I am getting an error like "webdriver not defined", so the browser fails to launch.

I am not able to understand what I am getting wrong here...I also tried to do it without the return also, but same result.

If this works, I can then import the module into any other script, whenever I need to use the block of import codes.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try

`driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\Users\nila9\drivers\chromedriver.exe")`

or

`driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Users\nila9\drivers\chromedriver.exe")`

Comment: the problem is not with the path as the script works if I simply remove the def part and run the lines just with the import statements. Its the webdriver which is failing to load if called from within the function